# How do I implement this model in CPLEX?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am new to **CPLEX**. How to write the code for this:
[image: formulation]

I have tried few ways but none seemed to work. I couldn't figure out how to code, I looked at many examples but I couldn't find anything similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with

```
range I=1..48;
range J=1..8;
range K=1..6;

int n=4;
int m=3;

int p[i in I]=i;

dvar boolean x[I][J][K];


minimize sum(i in I,j in J,k in K) p[i]*(k-j+1)*x[i][j][k];
subject to
{
  forall(i in 1..m, k in 1..n) sum(j in 1..n) x[i][j][k]==1;
  
  forall(i in 1..n) sum(j in 1..m,k in 1..n) x[i][j][k]==1;
  
  
}
```